# Why can't I append a cloned element to another parent?

Tags: javascript

I've got two divs:

```
<div id='div1'>
  <span>text</span>
</div>

<div id='div2'>
</div>
```

I'm trying to move the span from div1 to div2:

```
  var div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
  var div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');

  //cloning span
  var span = div1.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
  //removing span from the first div
  div1.removeChild(div1.firstElementChild);
  //trying to append new span to the second div but nothing happens
  div2.appendChild(span);
```

The span element is removed but isn't inserted in the second div.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a deep copy. [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) accepts an optional parameter

```
 var span = div1.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
```

[(here is a fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vdeFe/)

While `deep` is supposed to be `true` by default according to the new specification, in chrome and safari it defaults to false.

Comment: @KirillIvlev you're welcome, if it makes you feel any better, the new specification is on _your_ site `Node importNode(Node node, optional boolean deep = true);` https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-node-clonenode . It's not your fault. It's always better to explicitly say that you want a deep clone using this method because of that.